# JQuery validator.addMethod to validate checkboxes using class names

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having trouble using jQuery validator.addMethod to validate check boxes based on class names as opposed to names.

Take a look at this and tell me why the script doesn't work when placed within script tags inside the html.

The code is here: http://jsbin.com/ecozih/2

If you move the script over to the JavaScript window on JS bin it works.

If there is a easier way to do this, please let me know. An example would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
  <head>
<script src="hxxp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hxxp://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>
<script>
$.validator.addMethod('interests', function (value) {
return $('.interests:checked').size() > 0; }, 'Pick one or more');
var checkboxes = $('.interests');
var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e,i) { return $(e).attr("name")}).join(" ");
$("#subscribeForm").validate({
    groups: { checks: checkbox_names },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
             if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox")
               error.insertAfter(checkboxes.last());
             else
               error.insertAfter(element);
}
});
</script>
<form name="subscribeForm" id="subscribeForm" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" class="interests" value="1" name="group[1357][1]" ><label>Bananas</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="interests" value="2" name="group[1357][2]"><label>Oranges</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="interests" value="4" name="group[1357][4]"><label>Apples</label><br />
<label for="checks" generated="true" class="error" style=""></label><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
  </body>
```

Thank you

Comment: Wait, is this a real problem or an issue with how jsbin works?  And by having the same Javascript code in both the HTML and the JS panes, you are running it twice, I can see why that might be a problem.

Comment: Its a real problem. Its not working even on my dev server

Comment: You need to wrap your code within a `$(document).ready()` function.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to wrap your jQuery code within a `document.ready`. In other words, your jQuery is trying to select elements before the elements have even been constructed.  The `document.ready` fixes this.  Since the `form` does not yet exist when the code is called, the `document.ready` only fires off when the HTML DOM is ready.

jsFiddle Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/TCHYJ/

and your jsBin:  http://jsbin.com/ecozih/4/edit

**Quote**:  *"If you move the script over to the JavaScript window on JS bin it works."*

That's because, code inside the JavaScript panes of jsBin and jsFiddle wait for the DOM to load before being fired whether you use the `document.ready` or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/TCHYJ/1/

http://jsbin.com/ecozih/6/edit

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.validator.addMethod('interests', function(value) {
            return $('.interests:checked').size() > 0;
        }, 'Pick one or more');
        var checkboxes = $('.interests');
        var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e, i) {
            return $(e).attr("name")
        }).join(" ");

        $("#subscribeForm").validate({
            groups: {
                checks: checkbox_names
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox") error.insertAfter(checkboxes.last());
                else error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        });

    });​
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sparky, hard to believe it cost me 6 hours scratching my head :-) Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.  To be safe, _always_ wrap your jQuery in a `document.ready`.